# Bundler: do I have to use the same commandline options each time?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I had some problems with Bundler and stopped using it for a while. Now, I'm getting back to using it, and read up on it more this time and decided these are the first commands I should run:

```
bundle install --binstubs --path vendor
bundle package
```

I know that future calls to `bundle` will remember the path, but now I've updated my Gemfile with a new gem, should I run...?

1. `bundle install` - Bundler will work out that I already have the other gems cached, and I want executables to bin/.
2. <s>`bundle install --local` - Bundler needs to know I want to use the cached gems but remembers the other stuff.</s> This doesn't work (or, more precisely, isn't for this situation), just use `bundle install` and it won't reinstall current gems (although I've seen it do that which is why I asked)
3. `bundle install --local --binstubs` - Bundler isn't going to remember anything and I need to provide it.
4. Any other combination/commands I'm not aware of.

<s>And then, do I need to re-run `bundle package` again after this?</s> My experiments show me that re-running `bundle package` is not required, the cache is updated with new gems.

I did read the docs, (and a couple of blogs, though finding up-to-date ones is quite difficult) but this isn't clear to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain options are what bundler calls remembered options and are stored in `.bundle/config`. These remembered options don't need to be typed again and again.

According to the http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html#REMEMBERED-OPTIONS, the remembered options are `--deployment`, `--path`, `--binstubs`, `--without`

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I looked in the .bundle/config file and it has ` ---
  2 BUNDLE_PATH: vendor
  3 BUNDLE_BIN: bin
  4 BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'` which looks right.